# Can every manifold be embedded into a compact manifold of the same dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, examples-counterexamples

Can every connected smooth boundary-less manifold be embedded into a compact smooth boundaryless manifold of the same dimension ? If not, can someone please provide me with  a counterexample ? Thank you

Comment: The answer appears to be no: https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05995

Comment: What will you do with a surface of infinite genus or a helicoid, for example?

Comment: @TedShifrin: the helicoid is homeomorphic to the plane, so I am not sure it gives a counter-example, but a surface of infinite genus certainly does give a counter-example.

Comment: @RobArthan I was thinking of the two ends …

Comment: @TedShifrin: I don't see what you mean about two ends.

Comment: @RobArthan My fault — I was visualizing a helicoid of bounded radius. The helicoid with no boundary indeed has one end, just as the plane does.

Comment: Is there an easy argument for why the infinite genus surface $\Sigma$ does the trick? Intuitively, the homology classes coming from the "infinitely many holes" should remain linearly independent upon embedding $\Sigma \to \Sigma'$, where $\Sigma'$ is a compact surface. If that's true, we're done. Is there an easy way to see this? Or is there a simpler argument...?

Comment: @AlekosRobotis A compact manifold has to have "a finite number of holes" (cover it with a finite number of charts diffeomorphic to open balls). Hence, an infinite genus surface cannot be embedded as a submanifold of a compact manifold.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems to me that paper is concerned with compactifying manifolds by adding more boundary whereas OP is concerned with boundaryless manifolds, so these results don't seem to apply.

Comment: @Didier What precisely is your claim? It's not true in general that an open submanifold of a compact manifold has to have finitely generated homology (remove a sequence with one accumulation point from $S^2$ for example).

Comment: @Thorgott You are right, what I said is not clear at all and probably false.

Comment: @Thorgott , exactly my concern. It seems that these holes should not become filled in by embedding in a compact surface because they are not just punctures, but I don't see a nice way to argue this rigorously.

Comment: The proof that an infinite genus surface cannot be embedded into a compact surface is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554680/when-can-an-open-surface-be-embedded-into-a-smooth-compact-surface/4554693#4554693'). The proof works *mutatis mutandis* for compact surfaces with boundary.

Comment: @LeeMosher $\mathbb{R}^2-(\mathbb{Z}\times \{0\})$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}^2$ which embeds into $\mathbb{S}^2$. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: You are missing something: $\mathbb R^2 - (\mathbb Z \times \{0\})$ has genus $0$ because every simple closed curve separates it. For the same reason, every surface that embeds in $\mathbb R^2$ has genus $0$.

Comment: @LeeM I think you should turn your comment(s) into an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a counterexample explained in [my answer to a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554680/when-can-an-open-surface-be-embedded-into-a-smooth-compact-surface/4554693#4554693%27): an infinite genus surface cannot be embedded into a compact surface.

So for example the [Jacob's ladder surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob%27s_ladder_surface) has infinite genus, and hence cannot be embedded into a compact surface.